# How to set the focus to the form?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

When I click a button in my form and call a click event ,if i press the arrows buttons of the keyboard(up,left,right and down) the keydown event is not called
What can I do?
Sorry for my English

Comment: Your question is unclear. "The button does not recognized the arrow buttons". Do you mean that that your form doesn't take input while you are handling the keydown event? Or do you mean that after you finished handling the button clicked event the focus is not on the Button? What do you expect if a button has focus and the operator presses up-arrow? Please edit the question, so your requirements are specific. Can you show us what you do during the handling of the button click event?

Comment: And now? My problem is the first thing that you say but is after the keydown event, and it only happens with the arrow buttons

Comment: Please see [ask]. Provide a code (in the form of a [mre]) that is causing your error so that we can debug it and find the issue you are getting. Just saying you are getting errors without giving us the code when an error message is not present is quite useless and means it's hard to give specific help.

Answer (score 1):

No need to subscribe to `KeyDown event`. Try to override `ProcessCmdKey()`

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch(keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Up:
            Console.WriteLine("Up");
            break;
        case Keys.Down:
            Console.WriteLine("Down");
            break;
        case Keys.Left:
            Console.WriteLine("Left");
            break;
        case Keys.Right:
            Console.WriteLine("Right");
            break;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```